# Creating a new file that's locked while setting the last write time

Tags: c#

I'm creating files in C# from `InputStreams` and writing them to a public shared folder. I can't have someone else reading the file before I've set it's `LastWriteTime` property. I'm using the following code:

```
// Write file to disk
using (var fileStream = File.Create(fileName))
{
    webStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(path, timestamp);
```

A situation could occur where someone else reads the file before `File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc()` is called. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to set the correct sharing options when creating the filestream:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
```

Your last instruction should also be *inside* the using statement, as using guarantees that the file is closed when outside of it.

Comment: When I set the File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc() statement inside the using-block I get an IOException: "The process cannot access the file 'C:\test\myfile.csv' because it is being used by another process.". I'm saving the file to local disk for now, so no other process besides the one running my code could possible be using it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you explicitely setting the last write time attribute ?

Comment: I'm grabbing files from a remote website, their last-modified date is used later in a separate service to determine which file should be processed first.

Comment: If I simply write a byte-array to the FileStream then I get the same IOException.